# Functions button effects another function

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to add multiple stop watches on a page for tracking tracking how much time it takes users to complete tasks.  I have a function that works, I copied it and tried to make a second function duplicate with certain things change the buttons effect the other function.  Any help would be appreciated.

```js
<script>
   var time = 0;
   var running = 0;
   
   function startPause()
   {
    if(running == 0){
     running = 1;
     increment();
     document.getElementById("startPause").innerHTML = "Pause";
    }else{
     running = 0;
     document.getElementById("startPause").innerHTML = "Resume";
    }
   }
   
   function reset()
   {
    running = 0;
    time = 0;
    document.getElementById("startPause").innerHTML = "Start";
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
   }
   
   function increment()
   {
    if(running == 1){
     setTimeout(function(){
      time++;
      var mins = Math.floor(time/10/60);
      var secs = Math.floor(time/10 % 60);
      var tenths = time % 10;
      
      if(mins < 10){
       mins = "0" + mins;
      }
      if(secs < 10){
       secs = "0" + secs;
      }
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = mins + ":" + secs + ":" + "0" + tenths;
      increment();
      
     },100);
    }
   }
  </script>
  
   <script>
    var time = 0;
    var running = 0;
   
    function startPause2()
    {
     if(running == 0){
      running = 1;
      increment2();
      document.getElementById("startPause2").innerHTML = "Pause";
     }else{
      running = 0;
      document.getElementById("startPause2").innerHTML = "Resume";
     }
    }
   
    function reset2()
    {
     running = 0;
     time = 0;
     document.getElementById("startPause2").innerHTML = "Start";
     document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
    }
   
    function increment2()
    {
     if(running == 1){
      setTimeout(function(){
       time++;
       var mins = Math.floor(time/10/60);
       var secs = Math.floor(time/10 % 60);
       var tenths = time % 10;
      
       if(mins < 10){
        mins = "0" + mins;
       }
       if(secs < 10){
        secs = "0" + secs;
       }
       document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = mins + ":" + secs + ":" + "0" + tenths;
       increment();
      
      },100);
     }
    }
    
  </script>
```

```css
html {
 
 size: 100%,100%;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

h1{
 font-Family: Arial;
 color: #5573A9;
 font-size: 40px;
 position: static;
}
 
 body {
  display: block;
  margin:8px, dotted line;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  
  
 }
 
 


#output{
 position:center;
    width:120px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    border:3px solid #999;
   }
   
#output2{
 position: relative;
    width:120px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    border:3px solid #999;
   }
   
   table {
    display:table;
    border-collapse:seperate;
    border-spacing: 52px;
    border-color: #FFF;
   }
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  
  <title>Time Study</title>
  <h1>Time Study</h1>
 </head>
 
 <body>
      <table>
 <tr>
 <th>Bin</th>
 <th>Bulk</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
  <p id="output"></p>
  <div id="controls">
  <button id="startPause" onclick="startPause()">Start</button>
  <button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
  </div>
  </td>
  <td>
  <p id="output2"></p>
  <div id="controls2">
  <button id="startPause2" onclick="startPause2()">Start</button>
  <button onclick="reset2()">Reset</button>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: var time & var running are both shared from the global scope.

Comment: Thank you!
That stopped it from inteffering I changed all Var's and where they are declared to include a 2 now when i hit start i get 1 sec, pause then resume 1 second.  any idea there?